# How do I hyperlink JSON API return values with variable URL addresses?

Tags: javascript, json, hyperlink

I have an HTML/CSS search bar where people can type a keyword and, on click, my Open States JSON API code returns New Jersey state bills that match that keyword.

[Search Bar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2IbC.jpg)

[Screenshot of a Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRK8.png)

I want the bill titles that are returned to be hyperlinked to their page on the New Jersey state legislature site, but I can only find instructions for how to hyperlink a return with a static site.

Here is my JavaScript code so far (with API key removed):

```
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log($("#billID").val());
    var billSearchValue = $("#billID").val();
    if(billSearchValue=='') 
    { 
        alert("Enter Desired Query Parameters");
    } else{
        // console.log(billSearchValue);
    }
    var searchQuery = "&q=" + billSearchValue;
    var baseUrl = "http://openstates.org/api/v1/bills/?state=nj";
    var apiKey = "";
    var apiKeyParam = "&apikey=";
    var apiKeyParams = apiKeyParam + apiKey;
    var urlJSON = baseUrl + searchQuery + apiKeyParam + apiKey;
    // console.log(urlJSON);
    $.getJSON(urlJSON, function (data) {
        var billsVar = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            billsVar.push(val);
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < billsVar.length; i++) {
            var billList = "<li>Bill <ul class=\"ul-sub\">"
            var billTitle = "<li><strong>Bill Title</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['title'] + "</li>";
            var billCreatedAt = "<li><strong>Bill Created</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['created_at'] + "</li>";
            var billUpdatedAt = "<li><strong>Bill Updated</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['updated_at'] + "</li>";
            var billID = "<li><strong>ID</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['id'] + "</li>";
            var billChamber = "<li><strong>Bill Chamber</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['chamber'] + "</li>";
            var billState = "<li><strong>Bill State (Probably Don't Want/Need This)</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['state'] + "</li>";
            var billSession = "<li><strong>Bill Session</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['session'] + "</li>";
            var billType = "<li><strong>Bill Type</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['type'] + "</li>";
            var billSubjects = "<li><strong>Subjects</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['subjects'] + "</li>";
            var billBillID = "<li><strong>Bill ID</strong>: " + billsVar[i]['bill_id'] + "</li>";
            var billOutput = billList + billTitle + billCreatedAt + billUpdatedAt + billID + billChamber + billState + billSession + billType + billSubjects + billBillID + "</ul></li>";
            $("#jsonlist").append(billOutput);
        }
    });
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research I see that a bill hyperlink is like this:

`http://openstates.org/nj/bills/{Bill Session}/{Bill ID}/`

I can't test my code because I have no API key, but the solution could be something like:

```
var billTitle = '<li><strong>Bill Title</strong>: '
    + '<a href="http://openstates.org/nj/bills/' + 
    billsVar[i]['session'] + '/' + billsVar[i]['bill_id'].split(' ').join('') + '/">'
    + billsVar[i]['title'] + '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and now I'm getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined."

Comment: Oh sorry, left that one because I was testing with local variables. Fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason the hyperlinks are all leading to a 404 error.

Comment: Can you post one of them to see where the error is?

Comment: This is the first hyperlinked bill result for the keyword "taxi". The link leads to: http://openstates.org/nj/bills/216/NJB32834/. Please let me know if I should share something else/different. Thank you!

Comment: Try now, was using the long ID number instead of the Bill ID.